# Using Jenkins Pipeline to deploy code

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use Jenkins as my CI/CD tool. 
I am trying to use the Jenkins Pipeline plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin. I would like just to clone a repo on jenkins server and then copy it to a remote server.

I dont know if it is a best practice or probably should I use other tool to CI/CD?

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins Pipeline plugin is a great tool, with great capabilities.
Before you start, I suggest you read the [getting started](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) guide posted on Jenkins web site.
Try the examples and I think you'll find the answers to your needs.

In general, cloning and copying your files doesn't need the Pipeline plugin. It can be done with a simple free style where you clone and just `scp` your files to a remote server...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link for detailed help with examples

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/

as for as the requirement, find below the groovy script that does as per your expectation

```
node {
  loudStage "Cloning IaC repo"
  git url: 'https://github.com/repo'
  sh 'zip -q -r repo.zip repo'
  scpSshStep scpCommand: "repo.zip /sourcepath/repo.zip",
    command: "mkdir /targetpath; mv repo.zip targetfolder; cd targetfolder;unzip -q repo.zip; rm repo.zip",
    hostname: "${hostname}", username: "username", password: "password", port: '22'
  }
```

Comment: Does `scpSshStep` exist?